# How to return to previous fullscreen Terminal after closing a fullscreen X11 app?

Tags: macos, terminal, mojave, fullscreen, x11

I open Terminal app in fullscreen mode, by which Terminal sits itself in a new workspace. Then I run

`feh --fullscreen https://i.redd.it/tum2p9hdtex11.jpg`

It will open the image in fullscreen in Desktop workspace (Mac OS default workspace).

When I press `q`, I'd like it to return to my Terminal workspace. However, Mac OS drops me into Desktop workspace.

How can I make Mac OS to automatically switch me back to Terminal workspace?

Comment: `feh -w` opens in new window

Comment: @Buscar웃 it doesn't solve what I want. After I close the window, it doesn't return to Terminal workspace.

Comment: Strange, it does do that on my Mac, since I am closing the second window.